# How do I change the notification paging (or limit the number of pages) in this django plugin?

Tags: python, django, oop, notifications, installation

https://github.com/pinax/django-notification

In the "notices" in views.py, it should display a list of notices for the user.  And I got it to work.  The only problem is...it displays all the notices.  It floods the page.

How do I modify this function in views.py to set a limit to what should be displayed?  I did setup.py install.  Now, the app's code is in site-packages, and I don't want to modify the views directly.

Better yet, am I missing anything...maybe django-notification allows me to turn this on/off?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide a custom `notification/notices.html` template in order to get the `notices` view working at all, so I'm assuming you've already created that yourself.

If you just want to arbitrarily limit the number of notifications a user gets per page, then in your template you probably want to do something like...

```
{% for notice in notices|slice:":5" %}
    {{ notice }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will only display the first five notices.